# Making WPF User Control transformations internal

Tags: wpf, user-controls, converters

I am developing my system using WPF with MVVM and I am having trouble to find out the best way to solve the following problem:

I have a screen in which many components (User Controls) are drawn at specific positions. All components in the screen are rotated, translated and scaled according to binded variables calculated by the screen's VM.

However, each of this components could have a different center for the rotation, a different origin for the translation and a different scale, dependent of internal variables and the screen scale.

How is it possible to make this transformations calculated internally in the User Control? I think the easier approach is using the `Converter`, however since I have many different User Controls with different behaviours, I would have to create multiple converters very similar to each other, which would not be the ideal solution.

Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

A `UIElement` has only one [RenderTransformOrigin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.rendertransformorigin).
Some transformations allow you to set the origin for that transformation but in coordinates relative to the control bounds (e.g.: `125, 34`) not in proportional coordinates like the `RenderOrigin` (e.g.: `0.5, 0.75`)

So if you can use the coordinates you're good to go.

If not, you could compose the transformations by creating Transformation groups that first translate the control, then perform the transformation, and then translate the control back.

If you need more help, please post an example of what you are trying to achieve.